# How can I ensure my Highcharts don't break my flexbox layout?

Tags: css, highcharts, flexbox

I basically have two graphs and a sidebar.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating it:

https://jsfiddle.net/NibblyPig/b54qjavu/

Without `min-width: 0` in the CSS the layout is badly broken with it stretching off the screen somehow even though that shouldn't be possible with a parent width of 100%.

Without calling the chart reflow method at the bottom of the javascript, the charts overflow off the screen.

Reflow kinda fixes it but despite both divs having `flex-grow:1` they end up different sizes, again despite both having `flex-grow: 1`

If you resize the window itself, i.e. restore/maximise it the layout breaks even more, with the left div taking something like 20% of the width.

Any idea how I can fix this?

---

Pasted JS fiddle code below:

```
<div id='parent'>    
  <div id='columns'>  
    <div id='leftcolumn'>    
      <div id='chart1'>    

      </div>
      <div id='chart2'>

      </div>    
    </div>    
    <div id='rightcolumn'>
      This is the right column.
    </div>    
  </div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100vh;
  min-width: 0;
}

#columns {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
    min-width: 0;

}

#leftcolumn {
  display:flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-shrink: 1;
    min-width: 0;    
}

#rightcolumn: {
  flex-grow: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
    min-width: 0;    
}
```

JS:

```
  $(function () {
        var myChart = Highcharts.chart('chart1', {
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Statistics'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['ABC', 'DEF']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit eaten'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'This Month',
                data: [4, 1]
            }, {
                name: 'Average',
                data: [3, 2]
            }]
        });

        var myChart2 = Highcharts.chart('chart2', {
            chart: {
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'ABCDEF'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                    }
                }
            },
              series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'AXD',
            y: 67.34,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
        }, {
            name: 'ERT',
            y: 11.88
        }, {
            name: 'ASD',
            y: 20.78
        }]
    }]
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi @NibblyPig, That problem is a Highcharts issue reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6427 and it is tagged as `Undecided`. Please check the thread and let me know if this plugin: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5ue4pyvk/ solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this by applying `flex-basis: 50%` to the parent container and a call to resize upon first loading the page with `window.setTimeout(function () { myChart.reflow(); myChart2.reflow(); });`

Here is the updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/NibblyPig/b54qjavu/2/